# Remove finished threads from vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a number of jobs and I want to run a subset of them in parallel. E. g. I have 100 jobs to run and I want to run 10 threads at a time. This is my current code for this problem:

```
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <random>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t NUMBER_OF_THREADS(10);
    std::atomic<std::size_t> numberOfRunningJobs(0);

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::mutex maxThreadsMutex;
    std::mutex writeMutex;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 2);

    for (std::size_t id(0); id < 100; ++id) {
        if (numberOfRunningJobs >= NUMBER_OF_THREADS - 1) {
            maxThreadsMutex.lock();
        }
        ++numberOfRunningJobs;
        threads.emplace_back([id, &numberOfRunningJobs, &maxThreadsMutex, &writeMutex, &distribution, &generator]() {
            auto waitSeconds(distribution(generator));
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(waitSeconds));
            writeMutex.lock();
            std::cout << id << " " << waitSeconds << std::endl;
            writeMutex.unlock();
            --numberOfRunningJobs;
            maxThreadsMutex.unlock();
        });
    }

    for (auto &thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the for loop I check how many jobs are running and if a slot is free, I add a new thread to the vector. At the end of each thread I decrement the number of running jobs and unlock the mutex to start one new thread. This solves my task but there is one point I don't like. I need a vector of size 100 to store all threads and I need to join all 100 threads at the end. I want to remove each thread from vector after it finished so that the vector contains a maximum of 10 threads and I have to join 10 threads at the end. I think about passing the vector and an iterator by reference to the lambda so that I can remove the element at the end but I don't know how. How can I optimize my code to use a maximum of 10 elements in the vector?

Comment: Consider making a thread pool and reusing the existing threads.

Comment: Note that unlocking `maxThreadsMutex` while it is locked yields undefined behavior

Comment: why you keep all threads? Since you do not reuse, I think you can simply detach it and wait for some finish signal.

Comment: or you can simply wait for the last 10 thread.

Comment: @LWimsey: Do you mean unlocking while it is not locked?

Comment: @appleapple: That is exaz what I want to do but I don't know how. How can I know which are the last 10 threads? Maybe the first thread runs for one hour and the others run for one second.

Comment: @user4581301: Yes, I want to use a thread pool of 10 threads and reuse them. But how.

Comment: if you want a thread pool, you should not create 100 threads.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177407/discussion-between-thomas-sablik-and-apple-apple).

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, I meant unlocking when it is _not_ locked yields undefined behavior.. that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword "thread pool" helped me much. I tried boost::asio::thread_pool and it does what I want in the same way as my first approach. I solved my problem with

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <random>
#include <mutex>
#include <boost/asio/thread_pool.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/post.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::thread_pool threadPool(10);
    std::mutex writeMutex;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 2);
    std::atomic<std::size_t> currentlyRunning(0);

    for (std::size_t id(0); id < 100; ++id) {
        boost::asio::post(threadPool, [id, &writeMutex, &distribution, &generator, &currentlyRunning]() {
            ++currentlyRunning;
            auto waitSeconds(distribution(generator));
            writeMutex.lock();
            std::cout << "Start: " << id << " " << currentlyRunning << std::endl;
            writeMutex.unlock();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(waitSeconds));
            writeMutex.lock();
            std::cout << "Stop: " << id << " " << waitSeconds << std::endl;
            writeMutex.unlock();
            --currentlyRunning;
        });
    }

    threadPool.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't seem to require extremely fine-grained thread control, I'd recommend approaching this problem with OpenMP. OpenMP is an industry-standard directive-based approach for parallelizing C, C++, and FORTRAN code. Every major compiler for these languages implements it.

Using it results in a significant reduction in the complexity of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main() {
    constexpr std::size_t NUMBER_OF_THREADS(10);

    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 2);

    //Distribute the loop between threads ensuring that only
    //a specific number of threads are ever active at once.
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUMBER_OF_THREADS)
    for (std::size_t id(0); id < 100; ++id) {
        #pragma omp critical //Serialize access to generator
        auto waitSeconds(distribution(generator));

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(waitSeconds));

        #pragma omp critical //Serialize access to cout
        std::cout << id << " " << waitSeconds << std::endl;
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

To use OpenMP you compile with:

```
g++ main.cpp -fopenmp
```

Generating and directly coordinating threads is sometimes necessary, but the massive number of new languages and libraries designed to make parallelism easier speaks to the number of use cases in which a simpler path to parallelism is sufficient.